# pass parameters with ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

i trying to pass parameter from one site to the next site and use it but i have a problem!

store>index

```
<h1>All Priorities</h1>


<% @buildings.each do |building| %>
<div class="entry">
    <div class="img">
    <%= image_tag (building.photo.url)%></div>
    <div class=" disc">
    <h3>Name of the Bulding:  <%= building.title %></h3>
     <h4>Status: <%= building.status %></h4>
    Info: <%=sanitize(building.description)%>
    <div class="price_line">
        <span class="price">Price: <%= sprintf("€ %0.02f",building.price)%></span><br/>
        <div class="button">
        <%= button_to "I Want to See it", new_seeit_path(building.id), :method => :get%>

</div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <%end%>
    <div class="pages">
    <%= will_paginate @buildings %></p>
    </div>
```

in the next site when i press the button i want to see it it says :

```
http://localhost:3000/seeits/new.4?
```

and does not open the page

if i remove the (building.id) it says :

```
http://localhost:3000/seeits/new?
```

it takes me to the next site but without param

views>wish_receive.text.erb <= this send me those info on email

```
You got a wish from   <%= @seeit.name %> 
<%= @seeit.telephone_number %>
<%= @seeit.email %>
<%= @seeit.comments %>
```

routes

```
Projectproperties::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :seeits

  get "about/index"

  get "contact/index"

  get "store/index"

  resources :buildings
 root :to => 'store#index', :as => 'store'
end
```

seeits_controller

```
def new
    @seeit = Seeit.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @seeit }
    end
  end

  # GET /seeits/1/edit
  def edit
    @seeit = Seeit.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /seeits
  # POST /seeits.json
  def create
    @seeit = Seeit.new(params[:seeit])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @seeit.save
        Notifier.wish_received(@seeit).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to(store_url, notice: 'Thank you for your wish will contac you very soon.') }
        format.json { render json: @seeit, status: :created, location: @seeit }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @seeit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

rake routes command

```
      seeits GET    /seeits(.:format)             seeits#index
              POST   /seeits(.:format)             seeits#create
    new_seeit GET    /seeits/new(.:format)         seeits#new
   edit_seeit GET    /seeits/:id/edit(.:format)    seeits#edit
        seeit GET    /seeits/:id(.:format)         seeits#show
              PUT    /seeits/:id(.:format)         seeits#update
              DELETE /seeits/:id(.:format)         seeits#destroy
  about_index GET    /about/index(.:format)        about#index
contact_index GET    /contact/index(.:format)      contact#index
  store_index GET    /store/index(.:format)        store#index
    buildings GET    /buildings(.:format)          buildings#index
              POST   /buildings(.:format)          buildings#create
 new_building GET    /buildings/new(.:format)      buildings#new
edit_building GET    /buildings/:id/edit(.:format) buildings#edit
     building GET    /buildings/:id(.:format)      buildings#show
              PUT    /buildings/:id(.:format)      buildings#update
              DELETE /buildings/:id(.:format)      buildings#destroy
        store        /                             store#index
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what the exact problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show us your routes.rb file and what rake routes outputs?

---

Here we go.

In your routes.rb file, add this:

```
  resources :seeits do
    member do 
      post 'new'
    end
  end
```

In your seeits_controller.rb file, your new method should look like this:

```
  def new
      # raise params.inspect
      @seeit = Seeit.new
      @building = Building.find(params[:building_id])

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @seeit }
      end
    end
```

Lastly, in your view file, replace your button_to code with this

```
<%= button_to("I want to see it", {:controller => "seeits", :action => "new", :building_id => building.id})%>
```

Note that now, your button passes in the variable building_id as a parameter, allowing you to access the @building object.  The new action in your controller is now a post function, because we're sending information to the server.  Now you can use the @building in your new template.  Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, that routes.rb file.  Also, in your terminal, type in "rake routes" and post your output.  For your new_seeits_path, is that an action in your building controller?

Comment: the seeits is to send email. and all i want is to get the building title to send it with the email

Comment: Ok, hopefully last question.  How is the model SeeIt related to the Building model?  I'm guessing they're somehow joined, and you want to created a new SeeIt object, based off of the building id?

Comment: the seeit object is not to create something new but to show me form and fill it and then to send the informations to the email.BUT that i want is to sent and the building title (to know witch building wants to see)

Comment: WOW now is working with the passing!! THX!! but now how i can grab the parameter to send it with the email with the views>wish_receive.text.erb ?

Comment: i have try this code <%= @building_id.inspect%> in views>wish_receive and the email come with the word nil. do you know how to fix this?(witch is the problem) have to pass the parameter to the wish_receive again?

Comment: which controller and action is the views wish_receive.text.erb point to?  try putting "raise params.inspect" in your controller to the previous step before you get to the wish_receive template.  This will let you know if :building is even a parameter.  My gut is it's not, that's what @building_id

Comment: also it's <% = @builing.id.inspect %>  No underscore.

Comment: with putting "raise params.inspect" it has error :RuntimeError in SeeitsController#new . in the seeits>_form.html i have put <%= f.label @building.title%> and i can see the name of the building correct! but i cant include it in wish_receive. and if i put "<% = @builing.id.inspect %>" is says RuntimeError in Seeits#create , Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Comment: RuntimeError is the right error you should see.  Look at the hash below.  It should say something like this: {"authenticity_token"=>"ixdaubs3El2zCkYdhIMmW4kxi6ckJMmgw3Fzw22f4Aw=", "building_id"=>"1", "action"=>"new", "controller"=>"seeits", "id"=>"new"}.  This shows that the building_id is passed into the new action.  Try putting raise.params.inspect in the create action.

Comment: RuntimeError in SeeitsController#create , {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9bReP3nGlAbOPfgrW2EaEXBuaZBqqeVFoSexnyyJtck=", "seeit"=>{"name"=>"marios", "telephone_number"=>"99673609", "email"=>"linkinpark_8884@hotmail.com", "comments"=>""}, "commit"=>"Place Your Wish To See It", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"seeits"}

this means that it does not pass the parameter right?

Comment: yes.  in your form, i suggest using a f.hidden field.  Should look like this, <%= f.hidden_field :building_id, :value => @building.id %>

Comment: in _form i have put <%= f.hidden_field :building_id, :value => @building.id %> and works but when i push the submid button to sent the email it says ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in SeeitsController#create , Can't mass-assign protected attributes: building_id

Comment: i have but <%= f.hidden_field :building, :value => @building.id %>  in _form and now is taking the parameter "building"=>"4" (witch is right) but when i push the putton it says ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in SeeitsController#create , unknown attribute: building . i also included in model> seeit attr_accessible : building ! any ideas?

Comment: Building and Seeit models must have the proper association relationship.

Comment: all i want to do is to send the email with the building_id (wish_receive.text.erb , witch is the email content )

Comment: Use form_tag helper instead of form_for helper.  This way, :building_id is passed in as a parameter that is not attached to the seeit object.

Comment: with the answers nad your her help i have make it! i have pass the parameter and then i had to drop the table seeit and re-add it with one more colume building and works